# Custom General Link - Sitecore 10.2

Tags: custom-field

I have created the "Custom General Link" field type by duplicating the "General Link," as I have to add one additional control property that is "Telephone". I followed all the steps and was able to achieve the expected result both in content editor and experience editor mode.

I also created the "CustomGeneralLinkRender.cs" class to render and assign "href" for the telephone field, but with this, I am not able to see any saved data with text in the experience editor mode, and if I add the code like "GetLinkFieldValue.cs," like proper data, it is displayed in the experience editor mode but I am unable to edit it.

**Note :** When, I add the required code with the existing "General Link" field and add "Telephone" property everything works properly.

```
public class CustomGeneralLinkRender : Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue
{
    public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
    {
        if (this.SkipProcessor(args))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (args != null && (args.FieldTypeKey == "link" || args.FieldTypeKey == "general link" || args.FieldTypeKey == "custom general link"))
        {
            LinkField linkField = args.Item.Fields[args.FieldName];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkField.Url) && linkField.LinkType == "tel")
            {
                args.Parameters["href"] = linkField.Url;
            }
        }
    }
    protected override bool SkipProcessor(RenderFieldArgs args)
    {
        if (args == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        string fieldTypeKey = args.FieldTypeKey;
        string fieldName = "Custom General Link";
        if (fieldTypeKey == fieldName.ToLower())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return base.SkipProcessor(args);
    }
}
```